# Click Twitter's follower unfollowing button in CasperJS environment, from the follower's page

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I actually want to follow / unfollow Twitter accounts in a CasperJS environment. I am used to do some testing with a navigator (for example with Firefox or Chrome) before I write my JavaScript code. I have tried several button click syntaxes that just work great in the navigator, but not in the CasperJS environment.

For example, I log in to Twitter with Firefox, and go to this URL "https://twitter.com/googledrive" (it is an account that I am already following). I move the mouse over the "Follow / Unfollow" button and right click in order to inspect the button element. The navigator opens a console (just like F12). Then I right click on the element (in the HTML code) and select "Copy Unique Selector". Then I just have to write the following line in the Console bar :

```
document.querySelector("span.button-text:nth-child(3)").click();
```

Or even this one works :

```
document.querySelector(".button-text.unfollow-text").click();
```

And when I go back to my followings list, the Google Drive account has been removed.

I would like to do the same action in CasperJS environment. I am able to log in, go to the page containing the account I am following, click on the Google Drive account, and when I try to do the unfollowing click, CasperJS throws no error, and do the click action. But when I go to Firefox and refresh my page, I still have the same number of followings...

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: { userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0" }
});

var email = 'My Email';
var auth = 'My Password';

casper.start('https://twitter.com/', function() {
    this.fill('form.t1-form.signin', {
        "session[username_or_email]" : email,
        "session[password]" : auth
    },true);
}); //It leads me to my Twitter Dashboard

//Go to my followings list
casper.then(function(){
    console.log(this.getTitle());
    this.click("div.ProfileCardStats:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)");
    casper.wait(2000);
});

//I click one of the links to Google Drive page
casper.then(function(){
    console.log(this.getTitle());
    this.click("#stream-item-user-32468665 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)");
    casper.wait(2000);
});

//Unfollow action
casper.then(function(){
    console.log(this.getTitle());
    this.click("button.user-actions-follow-button");
    casper.wait(2000);
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.wait(1000, function(){
        this.back();
    });
    casper.wait(2000);
});

//Then I want to go back to my followings list
casper.then(function(){
    casper.wait(2000, function(){
        console.log(this.getTitle());
    });
});

casper.run();
```

Here is what the debugging says :

[image] which seems fine, just like if the button existed but the click action doesn't work at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I even tried with casperJS evaluate function, in order to use jQuery, but it still doesn't do the click action :
this.evaluate(function(){
  $('span.button-text:nth-child(3)').click();
});

Comment: The following didn't work either, but I get in the condition and I get the message "Button detected".
this.mouse.move("button.user-actions-follow-button:nth-child(2)");
if(this.exists("button.user-actions-follow-button:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3)")){

  casper.click("button.user-actions-follow-button.js-follow-btn.follow-button.btn:hover");

  console.log("Button detected");
 }

Comment: Did anyone already succeeded in clicking on this follow / unfollow button with CasperJS ? I would appreciate any hints that can allow me to understand my errors in my code, I am really stucked with this button click problem...

Comment: I have the same problem, it had worked some months ago, but it does not anymore. It seems twitter now protect itself from automation quite efficiently.